# Save/update widget outside admin panel

Tags: wordpress

Is there some way to update/save widget from page - not from admin ?

I create widget with charts and do not know how to update it from sidebar. I found of course form in admin:

```
<form action="" method="post">

  <input type="submit" name="savewidget" id="widget-chart_widget-2-savewidget" 
         class="button button-primary widget-control-save right" value="Save">
```

But what is this ID = widget-chart_widget-2-savewidget ... how this ID is created?

Comment: Can you provide more info about where are your code and whaht you want to do with it?

Comment: What does this change? I need to update/save widget from page. In what place and what data I want to change haven't got any relationship

Comment: The ID is created by `'widget-' . widget_name . '-' . widgetID . '-savewidget'` Asuming widget_name as the name (in the code) that you have use for that widget and widgetID as the unique ID for that kind of widget (if it's 2 this means that in some moment there have been two chart_widget in the page)

Comment: Thanks, soo I can take this->id and create form like in admin for widget ... will try

Comment: You're welcome. May you found this interesting: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29486/how-where-is-the-global-variable-wp-registered-widgets-filled Regards